# HttpClient.DeleteAsync and Content.ReadAdStringAsync always return null

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient, json.net, async-await

When I'm using `DeleteAsync` function in `HttpClient` *(System.Net.Http)* and retrieve the content with `Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` I always get `null` returned.

I've tried the same with `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` - and they always return some result.

**Here is my code:**

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://httpbin.org/");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = _client.DeleteAsync("/delete").Result;
string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(res);
```

I always get `null` returned.

**However, all of this works:**

**GET:**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync("/get").Result;
string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(res);
```

**POST:**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _client.PostAsync("/post", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(res);
```

**PUT:**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _client.PutAsync("/put", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(res);
```

But `DeleteAsync()` and `ReadAsStringAsync()` always return me `null`.

According to [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7/) you have to return body when returning status code 200 OK.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what's going on on the wire?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference on the result, but any reason why you block (call `.Result`) on `DeleteAsync` instead of awaiting it?

Comment: @cremor Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code never checks the message response for the StatusCode. Unlike WebClient, HttpClient does NOT throw when the StatusCode is not in the 2xx range.

I bet that if you check the [HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode.aspx)/[HttpResonseMessage.ReasonPhrase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.reasonphrase.aspx) values you will find that the server returned a code other than 200.

For example:

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://httpbin.org/");
...
var response = await _client.DeleteAsync("/delete");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var result=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    ....
}
```

You can also call the [EnsureSuccessStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode.aspx) method to throw an exception if the response status is not a success code:

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://httpbin.org/");
...
var response = await _client.DeleteAsync("/delete");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var result=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**EDIT**

By the way, running the following as is on .NET 4.5, returns a body:

```
        var  _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://httpbin.org/");
        var response = await _client.DeleteAsync("/delete");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
```

Adding the `Accept` header doesn't make any difference

Comment: Changed my code to use `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` - but that didn't change anything. The server respondes with 200 OK. But I always get null. http://pastebin.com/dKb8BfBD

Comment: Why do you thing this is wrong? The server may not have sent a body. You should check the server's API to see whether it returns anything on a DELETE. Besides, not all REST APIs respect the RFCs

Comment: I'm guessing ASP.NET Web API doesn't respect it. Because the method I'm using to deliver the data is exactly the same as POST and PUT. Weird.

Comment: ASP.NET Web API returns what you tell it to return. If you don't return anything for the DELETE verb, there is nothing to return. In other words, check your code

Answer (score 0):

I have same case... for now I dont know method overload for DeleteAsync which accept content parameters like post. So I switch API from Delete to Post.

Comment: I think switching HTTP verbs to use the incorrect one just because some code using it will not work is not the advisable route.

Answer (score -3):

**Do you know:**

```
base_address +  relative_address  

"http://www.youdomain.com/myservice/"  + "/test"  = "/test".
```

> This is why you get nothing